# Probability generating function of simple birth process

Tags: probability, generating-functions, birth-death-process

**Question:**

Suppose that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a $(1,(\lambda_n)_{n \geq 0})$ simple birth process with $\lambda_n = (n+1)\lambda$. Show that

$$\phi(t) := \Bbb E[z^{X_t}]= ze^{-\lambda t}+ \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \phi(t-s)^2 \, ds$$

Hint: condition on the first arrival time.

---

**Attempt:**

Let $Z_0$ be the time of first arrival, so $Z_0 \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$ with density function $f_{Z_0}(s)=\lambda e^{-\lambda s}$. Then

\begin{align}
\phi(t) & = \int_0^\infty \Bbb E[z^{X_t} \, | \, Z_0=s] \, f_{Z_0}(s) \, ds \\
& = \int_t^\infty \Bbb E[z^{X_t} \, | \, Z_0=s] \, \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, ds + \int_0^t \Bbb E[z^{X_t} \, | \, Z_0=s] \, \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, ds \\
\end{align}

In the first integral, $X_t = 1$ because $t<s$ so that this is before the first arrival time $Z_0=s$. Thus we get

\begin{align}
\dots & = \int_t^\infty \Bbb E[z \, | \, Z_0=s] \, \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, ds + \int_0^t \Bbb E[z^{X_t} \, | \, Z_0=s] \, \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, ds \\
& = \int_t^\infty z\lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, ds + \int_0^t \Bbb E[z^{X_t} \, | \, Z_0=s] \, \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, ds \\
& = ze^{-\lambda t} + \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s} \, \Bbb E[z^{X_t} \, | \, Z_0=s] \, ds
\end{align}

So far yet so close, I am having trouble dealing with the second integral.

Any hints?

Comment: Conditionally on $Z_0=s$, $X_t$ coincide in distribution with $X'_{t-s}+X''_{t-s}$, for two independent copies $X'$ and $X''$ of $X$. This is the branching property and translates as $E(z^{X_t}\mid Z_0=s)=E(z^{X'_{t-s}+X''_{t-s}})=E(z^{X_{t-s}})^2=\phi(t-s)^2$.